# Create PDF file from from API

Tags: python

I have an API that returns PDF file data, and want to know how to save that data to a file.

This is a snippet of how the data looks like:

```
%PDF-1.4
%äüöß
2 0 obj
<</Length 3 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode>>
stream
x�=��
1E����v���0�~���
```

I tried to base64 encode and decode it but then the PDF came out blank and tried to convert the data to bytes to write to the file, but still won't work.

I unsuccessfully tried:

```
data = format(response.text,'b') with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as f: f.write(data)
```

and also this:

```
data = base64.b64encode(response.text) with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as f: f.write(data)
```

Comment: Can you share the code which you used to "convert the data to bytes to write to file"?

Comment: data = format(response.text,'b')

with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)

Comment: And also tried this:  data = base64.b64encode(response.text)

with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)

Comment: Glad it's solved. In the future, please [edit] your question to give supplementary information. Each question should stand on its own, comments may be deleted in the future and code formatting works much better in questions than in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, you have said that you are using `response.text` to save the PDF to a file. This pre-converts the response stream to a text response, and so what you are seeing there is not quite the right result for downloading a binary file.

If you change this instead to the following, your PDF should be saved with the correct binary content:

```
with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as f: 
    f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Can't believe I didn't try that